# How Is "Super Laminate" flooring installed?

Tags: flooring, installation, vinyl-flooring

I recently learned about AABSO "Super Laminate" flooring (aka Vinyl flooring planks). It seems to have some advantages over standard laminate flooring when it comes to moisture resistance so I'm considering it (especially for our kitchen).

For some reason, I haven't been able to find installation instructions for it. Can someone summarize the procedure? Is it the same tongue-and-groove implementation as standard laminate? Or completely different?

-M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to depend on the range of flooring that you choose.  I found a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_a878ioli0) on YouTube showing it without the tongues, and I also found a seller with some [photographs](http://www.diyflooring.com/s.nl/it.A/id.68586/.f) showing the tongues on the edges of a piece.

This [review](http://www.floordujour.com/2010/05/aabso-vinyl-flooring-review/) backs up that assessment:

> Loose Lay Vinyl Plank Flooring (you literally can just unbox the floor and then install without glue or
>   anything!)
>
> Mid Level Vinyl Plank Flooring (this clicks together like laminate flooring and is INCREDIBLY well milled)
>
> High End Vinyl Plank Flooring (This is a wide planked handscraped floor that looks like wood and has a depth of  visual detail that can not be beat)

Answer (score 1):

You should read this http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/installing-laminateengineered-wood-floating-floors/ blog post.

It's geared towards wood laminates, but the process is the same.

The two major tips are:

1. Measure carefully and plan your layout so you don't end up with a skinny strip at either end.
2. Keep your grooves scrupulously clean.